# cat SQL files and pass to import schema

Tags: pipe

I am trying to import a series of .SQL files which map one file per DB object into mysql without calling mysql 50 times, something like:

```
mysql -u root < cat schema/db1/*.sql
```

This isn't working as "cat" is not a directory -- how would I accomplish this -- and why isn't what I have working? What am I not understanding about linux command piping???

EDIT | The database is created by the SQL file so this doesn't work either:

```
cat bridge_access/*.sql | mysql -u root bridge_access
```

Comment: What does your comment "as 'cat' is not a directory" mean?  Is that supposed to be related to an error message you're seeing?  If so, could you edit your message to include it.  If you just do the `cat` part do you see all the output you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command you're trying is trying to treat `cat` as a file, shoving it's contents into `mysql`'s STDIN. Instead, you need the results of the `cat` command shoved into STDIN, which can be done a couple different ways. The way I would do it would be to pipe the output of `cat` into `mysql`:

```
$ cat schema/db1/*.sql | mysql -u root
```

Equally validly, you can use:

```
$ mysql -u root < `cat schema/db1/*.sql`
```

Comment: Sorry, but #2 is not going to work. The closest would be `mysql -u root < <(cat schema/db1/*.sql)`.